# The icon disappears and null in my terminal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I updated my code thanks to your help. When I launch the app with Expo, I have two errors: 
1/ I lost my scan icon which does not appear in my screen. This icon appeared previously. The idea is to scan some barcodes in order to display relevant data stemming from products.
2/ In my terminal, when the app is launched with Expo, I have this message: Array[], null, null

I would appreciate your comments concerning my issues. All the best,

Here is my new code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Button,
  AsyncStorage,
} from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { FontAwesome5 } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";

function ProductsScreen() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setisLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");

      setData(data);
      setisLoading(false);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(data);
  return isLoading ? (
    <ActivityIndicator />
  ) : (
    <>
      {data ? (
        <FlatList
          data={dataArray}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <>
              <Text>{item.brand}</Text>

              <View style={styles.scan}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="barcode-scan"
                  size={40}
                  color="black"
                  onPress={() => {
                    navigation.navigate("CameraScreen");
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </>
          )}
        />
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
export default ProductsScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a little more? Having trouble making Asyncstroge setItem? If the vector icon is not visible,

react-native run-android,

You can try doing npm start --reset-cache.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your message. I could not be more explicit than the code I shared.